# Why do we need to support the function isFull() in a queue or stack?

Tags: function, stack, queue

Why do we need to support the function isFull() in a queue or stack?

We can store data on disk and load whatever size we can load in memory

In other words how can we run out of memory if we have very large disks?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, it serves the same purpose as `isEmpty()` function. Although you could use

```
    Stack s1 = new Stack() ; 
    if(s1.size == 0)
    {
        //  Do something.
    }
```

Suppose, you implement stack as an array in any language such as C#. Now, since you cannot modify the capacity of stack after creating the stack. You need to check whether the stack is full before pushing more elements on to the stack.
for eg:-

```
    Stack s1 = new Stack() ;
    while(!(s1.isFull()&&s2.isEmpty()))
    {
       int temp = s2.pop() ;  // s2 is another stack.
       s1.push(temp)
    }
```

Here, you want to push as many elements of s2 as possible onto another stack

Otherwise, you will need to do:-

```
    Stack s1 = new Stack() ; 
    while(!s2.isEmpty())
    {
       s1.push(s2.pop()) ;  // I am assuming that s2.pop() returns the popped element.
    }
```

In this case 
if the  no of elements is greater than the capacity of s1 then pushing elements onto s1 will throw exception.

Another real game experience, suppose you make a puzzle solving game and don't want to give the user more than say 25 moves to solve the puzzle, and you store the state of the puzzle in a stack. So, you can use the `isEmpty()` function to check whether the user is about to exceed the allowed no of moves.
Although there can be other methods to do the same, but you can use the `isEmpty()` function also to do the same.

```
    while(!s1.isEmpty())
    {
        // wait for the user to make move.
    }
```

Comment: If we implement the stack as an array, we cannot modify the capacity. But what if we are using pointers may be in C++.
Initially we have a null pointer then we want to push new item, we allocate memory for the new item dynamically in the heap.
As long as the heap has available slots I can allocate new memory for new elements and when the heap fails to allocate memory (THE FULL CASE) we can move the entire (or part of the elements present in memory) to the disk and allocate new elements in the memory.